# Reputation tab shows wrong change if downvoted answers were removed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, reputation-history

I noticed that, when I downvote an answer that subsequently gets deleted, the reputation tab in my profile shows a change of -1, even though it's unchanged from when I last checked.

Here's a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image: screenshot showing what I mean]

The highlighted events that occurred since I last checked are circled; I received an upvote, and downvoted two posts that were removed. Yet, the tab shows a change of 8, when it should be 10.

Comment: @PopularDemand I can assure you that it is my honest attempt at a freehand question mark and I'm not quite that bad at the maths.

Comment: Sorry... I was trying to poke fun at myself for having poor reading comprehension, not mock you.

Comment: Didn't view it as such. No offense done, no harm taken, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value up top does *not* include changes from deleted posts (see those 2 "+1 removed"?), this is by-design.

We can't keep both totals, it'd be a recalc every time you toggle the "show removed" textbox *and* a change in trigger behavior depending on the preference (which is way, *way*, ***way*** more complicated than the current implementation), so we elected to show a total that reflects the default selection (*not* showing deleted posts, the same as it's always been).

This may change later, if we can efficiently query this total and cache it (I'll take a look after my current project), but it's working as-intended at the moment.